# Any books/publications about what life was like before antibiotics?

Tags: homework, book-recommendation

Just wondering. We've been discussing antibiotic resistant bacteria a bit in lecture, and how we're slowly sinking into a pre-antibiotic era again.

Comment: Any medical literature before 1928 is about "life without antibiotics". Please add some details to your question. Have a look at the [tag-wiki](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/book-recommendation/info) for [tag:book-recommendation]

Comment: A google search with "life before antibiotics" gives a nice list of sources.